# Office 365 Group Conversations: Reply By Email

Tags: office-365, office-365-groups

I have been testing Office 365 Group Conversations, when starting a conversation an email goes out to the group as expected.

Contributing to the conversation via Outlook seems a bit odd. It comes from the group email and if I hit reply it sends it to the original poster and the response will not be visible in the conversation.

Hitting reply all will send to the original poster and the group, this reply will now appear in the conversation.

Remembering to use reply all so responses appear in the conversation doesn't feel right. Is this something that can be configured in Office 365 Groups?